# How to migrate jQuery libraries to Zepto.js in wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, zepto

I have a WordPress website with JQuery libraries and I want to migrate it to Zepto.js. How can I achieve this? Any Suggestions or guides?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function to add js file with jQuery dependency.

Try out this code:

```
function zillion_add_zepto_script()
{


    wp_enqueue_script('zepto-js', 'https://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zillion_add_zepto_script');
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me the file name where this code should be embedded?

Comment: you can add this code in your theme's functions.php.